# apache hive - load fixed width data which does not have row delimiter

Tags: hive

I wanted to load fixed width data with no row delimiter. I tried org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe as below:

```
create external table tbl_temp
(
f1 string,
f2 string,
f3 string,
f4 string,
f5 string,
f6 string,
f7 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "(.{3})(.{3})(.{2})(.{6})(.{1})(.{30})(.{5})")
LOCATION '/user/usrNm/dir1';
```

and the data is like

```
xxxyyyzzaaaaaabccccccc                       11111xxxyyyzzaaaaaabccccccc                       11111xxxyyyzzaaaaaabccccccc ccc
```

with no row delimiter. 
When I do a select only 1 record is shown. Other data is ignored.
How to load a fixed width file with no row delimiter.

Thanks

Comment: The scenario is not clear. Please add a data sample to your post - "as is", using copy-paste

Comment: Got the solution. Please ignore this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us your solution @Aavik?